# SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) -

Tags: magento, magmi

I am trying to import images using magmi. I am getting `SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) -` error.

I tried changing username and password for database.But I am unable to change, as I click save configuration they revert back to old one.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be due to different password given in `app/etc/local.xml` file, try to change this

Answer (score 2):

Your Databank is not connecting. There might be 4 possibilities

1) Maybe your host is not "localhost" maybe it's different. I had same problem and i figured out hat my host is different. It was like this.
 [CDATA[mysql55.ssl-net.net]]

2) Maybe your username is wrong

3) Maybe you have entered wrong password

4) Maybe you have typed invalid database name
![CDATA[xxxx_xxxxxx]]

Please check all of them carefully, i am sure your problem will be solved!

Comment: Thanks adder! I ran into a similar problem where my host was not localhost. Really helped a bunch because not many answers have included this. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Check your folder options, if you can not change "root" after save. Look into MAGMI WIKI for folder options set.

Answer (score 0):

I removed my `root` password then got this error.

Removed it from `/app/etc/local.xml` and still got the error.

I had to remove the contents of `/var/cache/` which fixed it.